# running python script on computer with python not installed

Tags: python, powershell, usb, portable-python

I have portable python 2.7.6.1 installed on a usb stick and am wanting to be able to plug this usb into my computer (which does not have python installed on it), and execute a powershell command which will run a .ps1 file within my usb drive, all the ps1 file will to do is run a command that will use the portable python interpreter to run a .py file which is saved on the usb stick as well.

is this possible? any constructive input is highly valued and greatly appreciated!

Thanks all

Comment: some people just like to complicate things

Comment: hence the name python beginner coder lol

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use a `.cmd`/`.bat` file to accomplish this so you don't have to worry about ExecutionPolicy / PoSH-specifics.

```
.\py2.7.exe file
PAUSE
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your picture... as my name suggests I am pretty new to this stuff

Comment: Create a new file, copy/paste what I wrote in my code block, save it whatever you want e.g. `file.cmd`.  When you launch that, it will do what you want.  So `.\pythonexecutable.exe filenametolaunch`.  The `.\ ` will look in the same directory as the `.cmd` file.